# Updating a column of only one table after retrieving data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have made two tables in my Xampp database using MySQL query. They contain the following columns;

```
casual_leave_application(pers_no, start_date, end_date, reason, date_of_application, status)
```

```
employees(employee_id, first_name, last_name, designation)
```

I have retrieved data from these two tables using the following query;

```
SELECT a.pers_no
     , e.first_name
     , e.last_name
     , a.start_date
     , a.end_date
     , a.reason
     , a.date_of_application
     , a.status 
  FROM casual_leave_application a
  JOIN employees e
    ON e.employee_id = a.pers_no 
 ORDER 
    BY a.leave_id
```

There can be one of the three values in the status column (Pending, Approved, Rejected). By default, it is set to 'Pending'. If I set the value from 'Pending' to 'Approved' or 'Rejected' from the front-end webpage, the corresponding value must be saved back to the table 'casual_leave_application'. For this purpose, I wrote the following commands;

```
UPDATE 'casual_leave_application' SET status='$Status' WHERE leave_id='$Leave_ID'
```

NOTE:

$Status -> Contains the updated value of the column 'status' (either 'Approved' or 'Rejected').

$Leave_ID -> Serial number of the submitted leave (primary key of the table 'casual_leave_application')

Everything is working well. However, the table is not getting updated with the new value of 'status'. How should I do this?

Comment: Try to retrieve `status` value for this `$Leave_ID` immediately after UPDATE - does old or newly set value is returned? Check for error during UPDATE. Check that the transaction is committed.

Comment: Anything enclosed in inverted commas is a string. And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound/executed queries